# Reusable model-specific tree structure with generic leaf wrappers

Tags: typescript, generics, types

How do I define a reusable tree-like type that defines my unique structure of properties, but allows parameterizing the wrapper type for each leaf?

I have the following code that represents the sate of my app in 3 different levels:

```
export interface LogicTree {
  series: Logic<Series>,
  base: {
    ageGroup: Logic<AgeGroup>,
    woodSpecies: Logic<WoodSpecies>,
    length: Logic<Length>,
    profile: Logic<Profile>,
  }
}

export interface StorageTree {
  series: Storage<Series>,
  base: {
    ageGroup: Storage<AgeGroup>,
    woodSpecies: Storage<WoodSpecies>,
    length: Storage<Length>,
    profile: Storage<Profile>,
  }
}

export interface ResultTree {
  series: Series,
  base: {
    ageGroup: AgeGroup,
    woodSpecies: WoodSpecies,
    length: Length,
    profile: Profile,
  }
}
```

Notice that I have the same structure and type variable usage in each of the 3 types.

To simplify making changes and explore translation between trees I would like to define my Tree structure just once and apply a different wrapper type for each of them. But I fail to do so.

Here are my attempts and the errors I get:

**1)**

```
export interface AbstractTree<Wrapper> {
  series: Wrapper<Series>>,
  ...
}
```

> Type 'Wrapper' is not generic.

**2)**

```
export interface AbstractTree<Wrapper<T>> {
  series: Wrapper<Series>>,
  ...
}
```

> 'Wrapper' is declared but never used.
>
> ',' expected.
>
> Cannot find name 'T'.

**3)**

```
export interface AbstractTree<T, Wrapper<T extends BaseValue>> {
  series: Wrapper<Series>>,
  ...
}
```

> 'T' is declared but never used.
>
> Cannot find name 'T'.
>
> 'BaseValue' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) it's not possible as of now.

Maybe you can swap the idea of wrappers around and add properties to generic types like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36788767/54091)?