# typescript variable with generic extending

Tags: typescript

I have a predefined interface:

```
export declare interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

I would like to have a class attribute that constraint the generic type. Something like this:

```
public componentType: Type<any extends MyComponentType>;
```

Is it possible ? Because I did not find the solution on Typescript doc and I can't find a syntax that is working.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652179/extending-interface-with-generic-in-typescript can give you an answer

Comment: why not just `public componentType: Type<MyComponentType>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the comment made by @Josh Wulf on the original post.

```
public componentType: Type<MyComponentType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want

```
export declare interface Type<A,T extends A = A> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

class MyComponentType {

}

class MyComponentType2 extends MyComponentType{

}

class foo {
    public componentType: Type<MyComponentType>;

    constructor() {
        this.componentType = MyComponentType2;
    }
}
```