# How to pass extra props to interface base in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following

```
interface IMessageBase {
    id: number;
}

const handler = ({ id }: IMessageBase): void =>
    console.log('id', id);
```

How can this interface be modified, so it accepts more properties? I've tried the following, but I wasn't able to get it to work:

```
interface IMessageBase<T> {
    id: number;
    ...T;
}

const handler = ({ id, name }: IMessageBase<{ name: string; }>): void =>
    console.log('id, name', { id, name });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652179/extending-interface-with-generic-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your interface a type intersection !

```
type IMessageBase<T> = { id: number; } & T

const handler = ({ id, name }: IMessageBase<{ name: string; }>): void =>
  console.log('id, name', { id, name });
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgshAzoghgcwgIRYiAeAFQD4oBeKAbwCgooBLAEwC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwDcVAL5QAZFAJUqAYwD2rRMCgALFKwYAbfmSgAKCvQYAaNik7RhLeElQZsuPIdbmILJXzqs0AqMKIAlCwAbnKMZEQ0UPKKctoAdJpyaHoA5IymLhappoYZZhZ%20AQJAA)

Comment: Is it possible to make the `T` in `IMessageBase<T>` optional?

Comment: You can pass a default value to `T` : ``IMessageBase<T = {}>`

Answer (score -1):

You could also just extend the interface:

```
interface IMessageBase {
  id: number;
}

interface IMessageBaseWithName extends IMessageBase {
  name: string
}

const handler = ({ id, name }:IMessageBaseWithName) => {
  console.log('id, name', {id, name});
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I currently have set up, and trying to get rid of